# i am not able to create appropriate mongoose schema for this

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database-schema

i am not able to create a good mongoose schema.
the statement is 
1. we will be creating task for our users, this task gonna have start date and end date 
2. user will be accepting and rejecting task, if accepted they must do some work for this task

i am having problem in, 
1. how users will be seeing accepted and rejected task in their profile, i cannot add a isAccepted field in task schema, as multiple users will be assigned a single task 
2. how to create schema in such way, that i can filter results ( what user is accepted what task)

Comment: Hey, provide the best schema you can come up with and then ask the questions again

Comment: i have created a schema,
{
title:"",
startdate:"",
enddate:"",
assignedUsers:[{id:"1",isAccepted:"true",id:"2",isAccepted:"false"}]
}

Answer (score 0):

Then why not make assignedUsers an array that contains objects which include user id and if it is accepted?

```
{
  title:"",
  startdate:"",
  enddate:"",
  assignedUsers:[
    {
      id:"1",
      isAccepted:"true"
    },
    {
      id:"2",
      isAccepted:"‌false"
    }
  ]
}
```